# Python, random integer and colour assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am relatively new to python (3.14) and I am trying to define a new function called `getColor`. And with this I want to randomly return one of three colours. I want to use `random.randin(1,3)` in a variable, and want the return of 1, 2, and 3 to return different colours in each case!

So far my code looks like this

```
import turtle

w=turtle.Screen()
tess= turtle. Turtle()

import random
random.randint(1,3)


def getColor():
   return
```

i am not sure what to put for the coordinates, or how to go about getting colours for each of the three possible integers.
If any one has any pointers that would be amazing

Comment: Sure, I'll give you some pointers! 0x4810A94F and 0x581BC4C3. Let me know if you want any more.

Comment: In all seriousness, what do you mean by returning "different colours". Do you mean a string that contains "blue", "green", "red", or a color object from somewhere?

Comment: This is the question im trying to answer: define a function called getColor. Pick one of three colours to randomly return .  To do this, you first have to import random. The function randint returns a random whole number that is at least 1 and at most 3.  Finally, check the value in the variable to see if it is 1, 2, or 3 and return a different color in each case. If that clarifies anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice

def get_color():
    return choice(['red', 'yellow' 'blue'])
```

This is one way to do it using `choice()` from the `random` module. It will pick a random element from the list you give it.

If you want to use `randint`:

```
from random import randint

def get_color():
    colors = ['red', 'yellow' 'blue']
    return colors[randint(1, 3)]
```

Comment: Nice usage of the commonly overlooked choice, my preference for these types of problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats super helpful! How do i get this to return something though? Because when I run the module it works but its just blank and doesn't return anything?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't draw anything?